# How can one solve this differential equation? (Optical Fibers with a tanh(x) index)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, hyperbolic-functions

The differential equation for a optical fiber with a refractive index $n(r)$ is given as
$$\nabla^{2}_{\perp}A(r,\theta)+(k^{2}n(r)^2-\beta^2)A(r,\theta)=0.$$ 
which is separable in cylindrical coordinates, $A(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$. 
The radial DE follows as
$$ r^{2}R''+rR'+[r^{2}(k^{2}n(r)^{2}-\beta^{2})-m^{2}]R=0. $$
For a step function index ($n_{0}>n_{1}$, $\Delta \equiv n_{0}-n_{1}$),
$$n(r)=\cases{n_{0} : r\leq a\\n_{1}:r>a} \implies R(r)=\cases{c_{1}J_{m}(r\sqrt{k^{2}n_{0}-\beta^{2}}) : r\leq a\\c_{2}K_{m}(r\sqrt{\beta^{2}-k^{2}n_{1}}):r>a}$$
the radial part becomes a Bessel function. In a similar way, if $n(r)$ is quadratic one obtains a Gaussian with a Laguerre profile (is very similar to the Bessel's).

$\textbf{My question is:}$ If one has a index function such as $n(r)=n_{1}+\Delta f(\alpha r)$ where $\alpha$ is a parameter of how smooth the transition is. By applying the approximation $n(r)^2\approx n_{1}^2-2\Delta n_{1}f(\alpha r)$ and setting $f(\alpha r)=(1-\tanh^2(\alpha r /a))$ one obtain the radial equation,
$$ r^{2}R''+rR'+[r^{2}(k^{2}n_{1}^{2}-\beta^{2}+2\Delta n_{1}k^{2}(1-\tanh^{2}(\alpha r /a)))-m^{2}]R=0. $$ 
For simplicity I rewrite it as 
$$ r^{2}R''+rR'+[r^{2}(A-B\tanh^{2}(\xi r))-m^{2}]R=0, $$
where $A=k^{2}n_{0}^{2}-\beta^{2}+2\Delta n_{1}k^{2}$, $B=2\Delta n_{1}k^{2}$, $\xi=\alpha/a$. It is possible to make a change of variable or use other method in order to solve this DE?

$\textbf{Bonus:}$ I also tried with other index fuctions
$$
f(r)=\left[ \tanh(\alpha (a-r)/a)+1 \right]/2
$$
which returns
$$
r^2R''+rR'+[r^2(A+B\tanh(\xi (a-r)))-m^2]R=0
$$
where $A=k^{2}(n_{1}^2+\Delta)-\beta^2$, $ B=n_{1}k^{2}\Delta$, $\xi=\alpha /a$,
but with no success.

Comment: @Harry49, Yes i am looking for a way to generate an analytical solution, a power series might work but by how Tanh(x) expands with a taylor series i think is very complicated. Good thing is that in the region outside (r>a) we expect to have a $K_{m}(x)$ Bessel function, alll the magic happens in the inside..
Why? Well, i need to obtain R(r) to calculate the dispersion properties of the waveguide... is part of a homework.

Comment: There are many statements here ... and no questions, even in the part labelled "My question is".

Comment: @EricTowers. you are right, sorry if i wasn't clear. I wonder how one might solve the two differential equations.